# Running Chromium as nobody

Tags: arch-linux, users, chrome

How (on earth) do I run Chromium as the nobody user? Selected failures (in Openbox):

```
su nobody chromium
```

> This account is currently not available

```
sudo -u nobody chromium
```

> [0316/203558.490760:FATAL:chrome_main_delegate.cc(442)] Check failed: process_type.empty(). Unable to get the user data directory for process type: zygote
>   ...

```
sudo -u nobody chromium --user-data-dir=/root
```

> No protocol specified
>
> [595:595:0316/203827.174040:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] Gtk: cannot open display: :0

```
sudo -u nobody chromium --user-data-dir=/home
```

> No protocol specified
>
> [615:615:0316/203909.792019:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] Gtk: cannot open display: :0

My specs:

Linux arch 4.10.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Feb 26 21:08:53 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Chromium 57.0.2987.98

```
cat /etc/passwd:
...
nobody:x:99:99:nobody:/:/usr/bin/nologin
...
```

I prefer nobody because running Chromium as root is strongly discouraged and it seems to stupid to create a user just for running Chromium

**UPDATE:**

```
xhost local:root; su -pc 'env -i DISPLAY="${DISPLAY}" chromium' nobody
```

run by root in an X session **works** (if you want to make local connections to X server as root, `local:root` is much safer than `+`). Still, there were two errors:

> Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
>   [629:629:0323/170000.968320:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request
>   for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain

Get rid of the first one w/

```
mkdir /home/nobody; chown -R nobody:nobody /home/nobody; su -pc 'env -i DISPLAY="${DISPLAY}" HOME=/home/nobody chromium' nobody
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the user whose current `X` session is up:

```
$ xhost +
$ su - -c "DISPLAY=\"${DISPLAY}\" /bin/sh"
```

The first step, `xhost +`, allows any user to connect to the current `X` session<sup>1</sup>.  The second step is unnecessary if you were already `root`<sup>2</sup>.  Next, you will change to `nobody` and run `chromium`:

```
# su -p -c "env -i DISPLAY=\"${DISPLAY}\" chromium" nobody
```

The `-p` preserves the environment, allowing the locked user to "log in".  Then `env -i` clears the environment, which is probably more secure but may or may not be what you want.

---

<sup>1</sup> I assume there is a way to grant access only to a specific other user, but I don't know what it is.

<sup>2</sup> Common practice is to create a non-`root` account for typical day-to-day activities, only switching to `root` for administrative tasks.

Comment: I see you skipped the "change to nobody" part. `su nobody` gives  "This account is currently not available" (see the text); `sudo -u nobody -s` works but doesn't influence the result, which will be (w/ or w/out it, and after completing all your steps) "Chromium can not be run as root"

Comment: @jaam Well, almost.  Merely a typo, not forgetting.  See edit.  This does work and has been tested — the `-p` is what allows the locked user to log in.  You definitely don't want to use `sudo -s`.

Comment: @jaam Well, I should say "almost tested" — I don't have `chromium` installed, so I used `xev`.  `firefox` (my preferred browser) doesn't work with the `-i` switch of `env`, and I also had to create some directories to get `firefox` to start.  Chromium may have similar issues.  I ended up creating `/nobody` with owner and group `nobody`, permissions `700` and also passed `HOME=/nobody` to `env`.